# Unable to build jQuery ui with webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, jquery-ui, webpack

I'm unable to successfully include jQuery UI in my project using webpack. jQuery has been working, but when I visit a page of my app that requires jQuery-UI I get the following warning:

> jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).draggable is not a function TypeError: $(...).draggable is not a function

And error:

> jquery.js:4055 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).draggable is not a function

I'm nearly brand new to building javascript code using webpack/node, so it's very possible I've made a naive mistake.

This is my config file:

**config.js**

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');


module.exports = {
    entry: './src/js/index.js',
    mode: 'development',
    output: {
        filename: 'index.js',
        path: 'path/js',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(scss)$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'css-loader',
                    'sass-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                enforce: 'pre',
                use: ['source-map-loader'],
              },
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: '../css/index.css',
        }),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            $: 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
            'window.$': 'jquery',
        })
    ],
    resolve : {
        alias: {
            // bind version of jquery-ui
            "jquery-ui": "jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js",
            // bind to modules;
            modules: path.join(__dirname, "node_modules"),
        }
    },
}
```

My entrypoint:

**index.js**

```
import '../sass/index.scss';
const $ = require("jquery");
require('webpack-jquery-ui');
require('webpack-jquery-ui/draggable');
global.$ = global.jQuery = $;
import 'bootstrap';
```

Each time I make a change I run the command:

`npx webpack --config config.js`

There are no errors output from this.

Where am I going wrong?

**Update**
Upon Chris G suggestion in comments I've tried the following:

```
import '../sass/index.scss';
const $ = require('webpack-jquery-ui');
global.$ = global.jQuery = $;
import 'bootstrap';
```

Upon rebuilding I get a series of errors in the console such as:

```
ERROR in (webpack)-jquery-ui/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'jquery- 
ui/themes/base/autocomplete.css' in 
'.../webpack/node_modules/webpack-jquery-ui'
@ (webpack)-jquery-ui/index.js 57:0-49
@ ./src/js/index.js
```

This is what's returned when running "npm install --save jquery jquery-ui"

npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '.../webpack/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '.../webpack/package.json'
npm WARN webpack No description
npm WARN webpack No repository field.
npm WARN webpack No README data
npm WARN webpack No license field.

Could this now be an install problem?

Comment: According to the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-jquery-ui) you don't need to include `jquery` because `webpack-jquery-ui` already contains both.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisG - I've made a tweak based on your suggestion and updated the question to explain what happens. Struggling to re-build the code, I must have mis-understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, there are couple of things you need to do:

- All you need to do is to only install `webpack-jquery-ui`.
- I don't think you should are now resolving the correct `jquery-ui` in your `webpack.config.js`, just remove that alias of `"jquery-ui"`

```json
resolve: {
  alias: {
    // bind to modules;
    modules: path.join(__dirname, "node_modules"),
  }
},
```

- Finally, I don't think `webpack-jquery-ui` exports a `jquery` object for you so don't assign and export it in global anymore since it's currently available in your module with `ProvidePlugin`. So just simply write like following:

```js
import '../sass/index.scss';

require('webpack-jquery-ui');
require('webpack-jquery-ui/draggable');

// $ is available in the module via `ProvidePlugin`
global.$ = global.jQuery = $;
import 'bootstrap';
```

Comment: Thanks - after actioning I get a long list of errors all very similar for different parts of jquery-ui:

ERROR in ./node_modules/jquery-ui/themes/base/accordion.css 11:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (11:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|  * http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#theming
|  */
> .ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header {
|  display: block;
|  cursor: pointer;
 @ (webpack)-jquery-ui/index.js 56:0-46
 @ ./src/js/index.js

Comment: It looks like to import css automatically but you forgot to handle this file. Just try add the `css` files for your css loaders by changing to `test: /\.(scss|css)$/,`

Comment: Boom! You solved it :D Thanks a bunch. I'm thinking these errors will make more sense in a couple of weeks time of using webpack to build my code.